# C# IList parameter causes inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#, generics, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to create a class in c# using VS2005 as follows:

```
public class MyClass
{
        private string reference;
        private IList<MyClassItem> items;

        public MyClass(string reference, IList<MyClassItem> items)  // error here
        {
            this.reference = reference ;
            this.items = items;
        }

        public string Reference { get { return this.reference ; } set { this.reference = value; } }
        public IList<MyClassItem> Items { get { return this.items; } set { this.items = value; } }   // error line
}

public class MyClassItem
{
        private string id;
        private string name;

        public MyClassItem(string id, string name)
        {
            this.id= id;
            this.name= name;
        }
        public string Id{ get { return this.id; } set { this.id= value; } }
        public string Name { get { return this.name; } set { this.name= value;}}

}
```

I got error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.IList<Library.Model.MyClassItem>`' is less
>   accessible than method '`Library.Model.MyClass.Jurnal(string,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList<Library.Model.MyClassItem>)`'    D:...\MyClass.cs   15  16  Library
>   Error 4   Inconsistent accessibility: property type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.IList<Library.Model.MyClassItem>`' is less
>   accessible than property
>   'Library.Model.MyClass.Items' D:...\MyClass.cs   28  34  Library

Comment: Are you absolutely *certainly* that `MyClassItem` is public as you've shown it? Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem? Are these classes nested at all?

Comment: The posted code does not cause any errors. You made an error while copy/pasting or when shortening the code.

Comment: @JonSkeet right on I missed out 'public' in MyClassItem in my code...thank you guys have a great day

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can imagine ist that you defined `MyClassItem` as a part of other class, which ist private, protected or internal, for example:

```
internal class MyOtherClass
{
    //MyOtherClass properties and functions

    public class MyClassItem
    {
    }

}
```

Just move `MyClassItem` directly into the namespace and this should solve the problem